# is the following true: $|a-b| = ||a|-|b||$?

Tags: absolute-value

is $|a-b| = \bigg||a|-|b|\bigg|$ ?

I have tried a few examples and they seems to come out true, but I can't find any rule stating it.

Is it true for all $a$ and $b$? Or am I missing something?

Please notice I'm **not** talking about $|a-b| = |a| - |b|$, I know this one does not hold.

Comment: The last line is unnecessary, I believe.

Comment: $\left|\left|a\right|-\left|b\right|\right|\leq\left|a-b\right|$
This is true for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: You didn't try any negative number, did you ? Actually, there is no point trying positive values, as $a=|a|$ and $b=|b|$ will trivially make the equality true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not. 
Take $a=1$, $b=-1$. Then
$\lvert a-b\rvert = 2$ but $\lvert\lvert a\rvert-\lvert b\rvert\rvert = 0$.

(You only have an inequality, the [reverse triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality): $\lvert a-b\rvert \geq \lvert\lvert a\rvert-\lvert b\rvert\rvert $.)

Comment: To generalize, when one of $a$ or $b$ is positive and the other is negative, then $|a - b| \ne ||a| - |b||$.

Comment: Indeed -- see Fermat's answer (above, or below, depending on what Math.SE will eventually decide).

Answer (score 5):

It is true if and only if $ab\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Squaring, you get

$$(a-b)^2=(|a|-|b|)^2,$$
which simplifies to
$$ab=|a||b|,$$
not a valid identity.

Comment: This proves the fact that $ab\geq 0$ for the equation to hold since the equation you found holds iff $a,b$ have the same sign which automatically implies $ab\geq 0$. This concludes Fermat's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

if we take
$a=2$ and $b=-1$  I get:
$$|2-(-1)|=3$$
and
$$ ||2|-|-1||=1 $$